# How to install Bazaar to a shared server via SSH?

Tags: python, installation, bazaar

If I have SSH access to a shared server (running centOS) and I want to install Bazaar. I do not have root access, but Python is already installed on the server, so that shouldn't be a problem.

I really don't know where to begin after logging into the server. I'm assuming the first step is to copy the Bazaar application files onto the server... but I don't know where to put them.

If it helps, I will be using the shared server as a repository - I won't be doing any checkouts or anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Installation FAQ](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/InstallationFaq):

> ### Install in home directory
>
> You can install Bazaar into home directory, in `~/bin`. This method requires that `~/bin` is in your `$PATH` and that `~/lib/python` is in your `$PYTHONPATH`.
>
> ```
> % python setup.py install --home $HOME
> ```

However, if you are truly *only* using it as a repository, there's no need to install Bazaar.  [This how-to](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-bzr-over-ssh-with-no-bzr-server) explains how to set up a Bazaar repository on a server that only has SSH but no Bazaar.  It won't get you quite as good performance as `bzr+ssh`, but you would actually need to run a Bazaar server to get `bzr+ssh` anyway; you may not have that right on your shared server.